# Derivatives near optimal points

Tags: mathematical-economics

On page 52 of [What Sustains Social Norms and How They Evolve?](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S016726810300221X), Assumption 1 is as follows:

> **Assumption 1:** $d$ is continuously differentiable, $d'(x) \ge 0$ for all $x<0$ and $d'(x) \leq 0$ for all $x>0$ (it follows that $d'(0)=0$).

I don't understand the use of $\ge$ and $\le$ here. If $d'(0)=0$ implies a maximum is obtained at $x=0$, then every $x$ to the left of $0$ should have a strictly positive derivative and every $x$ to the right of $0$ should have a strictly negative derivative (i.e., $>$ and $<$ should be used).

What is the meaning behind $d'(x) \ge 0$ and $d'(x) \le 0$?

**Edit**: $d(g-\eta)$ is a function representing the disutility from social disapproval, where $g$ is a tip at a restaurant as a percentage of the bill and $\eta$ is the norm tip. The consumer takes as given $\eta$ (i.e., the social norm) and chooses $g$ to minimise the social disutility $d(x)$; i.e, bring it closer to $0$, where $x=g-\eta$.

Note: there is a trade-off to minimising $d$ that is probably not necessary to understand for my question.

Comment: The question would be somewhat more self contained if you were to include what $d$ is meant to describe.

Comment: @Giskard I have included a brief description of $d$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumption 1 ensures that $x=0$ is *a* maximum, but perhaps not *the* only maximum. It is possible that function does not have a 'peak' at 0, but a plateau. E.g.;

$$
f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
-(x+1)^2 & \text { if } \ x < -1 \\
0 & \text { if } \ - 1 \leq x \leq 1 \\
-(x-1)^2 & \text { if } \ 1 < x 
\end{array}
\right.
$$

[image]

For reference, [the Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) code of the above piece-wise function is

> y=\left{x<-1:-\left(x+1\right)^{2},-1\le x\le1:0,1<x:-\left(x-1\right)^{2}\right}